# faster way to calculate a rolling sum in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, offset

To calculate a volume weighted moving average (VWMA) I am collecting a sum(price*volume) and dividing it by the sum(volume).

I need a faster way to get a value from the previous row and add it to a value on the current row.

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import repeat

df = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': ['16:00', '15:00', '14:00', '13:00', '12:00', '11:00', '10:00', '09:00', '08:00', '07:00', '06:00', '05:00', '04:00', '03:00', '02:00', '01:00'],
'time': [1800, 1740, 1680, 1620, 1560, 1500, 1440, 1380, 1320, 1260, 1200, 1140, 1080, 1020, 960, 900],
'price': [100.1, 102.7, 108.5, 105.3, 107.1, 103.4, 101.8, 102.7, 101.6, 99.8, 100.2, 97.7, 99.3, 100.1, 102.5, 103.9],
'volume': [6.0, 6.5, 5.4, 6.3, 6.4, 7.1, 6.7, 6.2, 5.7, 1.2, 2.4, 3.9, 5.2, 8.9, 7.2, 6.5]
}, columns = ['dtime', 'time', 'price', 'volume']).set_index('dtime')

df.insert(df.shape[1], "PV", df['price']*df['volume'])
df.insert(df.shape[1], "flag", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "PVsum_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "Vsum_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "VWMA_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
```

Which is

```
df = 
       time  price  volume      PV   flag  PVsum_2  Vsum_2  VWMA_2
dtime                                                             
16:00  1800  100.1     6.0  600.60    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
15:00  1740  102.7     6.5  667.55    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
14:00  1680  108.5     5.4  585.90    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
13:00  1620  105.3     6.3  663.39    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
12:00  1560  107.1     6.4  685.44    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
11:00  1500  103.4     7.1  734.14    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
10:00  1440  101.8     6.7  682.06    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
09:00  1380  102.7     6.2  636.74    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
08:00  1320  101.6     5.7  579.12    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
07:00  1260   99.8     1.2  119.76    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
06:00  1200  100.2     2.4  240.48    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
05:00  1140   97.7     3.9  381.03    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
04:00  1080   99.3     5.2  516.36    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
03:00  1020  100.1     8.9  890.89    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
02:00   960  102.5     7.2  738.00    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
01:00   900  103.9     6.5  675.35    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Right now I am using a for loop to check each row if 'flag' is set.

```
#----pseudo code----
#for each row in df (from bottom to top, excluding the very bottom row)
#   if flag[row] is not set:
#      PVsum_2[row] = PV[row] + PV[row + 1]
#      Vsum_2[row]  = volume[row] + volume[row + 1]
#      VWMA_2[row]  = PVsum_2[row] / Vsum_2[row]
#      flag[row] = 1.0
#----pseudo code----

my_dict = {'dtime'  :   0,
           'time'   :   1,
           'price'  :   2,
           "volume" :   3,
           'PV'     :   4,
           'check'  :   5,
           'PVsum_2':   6,
           'Vsum_2' :   7,
           'VWMA_2' :   8}

for row in reversed(range(len(df)-1)):
    # if flag value is not set (i.e. flag == 0)
    if not df['flag'][row]:
        # sum of current and previous PV (price*volume) values
        a = df['PV'][row] + df['PV'][row+1]
        df.iloc[row, my_dict['PVsum_2']-1] = a
        
        # sum of current and previous volumes
        b = df['volume'][row] + df['volume'][row+1]
        df.iloc[row, my_dict['Vsum_2']-1] = b
        
        # PVsum_2 / Vsum_2
        c = (a / b) if b != 0.0 else 0.0                                                 
        df.iloc[row, my_dict['VWMA_2']-1] = c
        
        # set check value to 1.0
        df.iloc[row, my_dict['flag']-1] = 1.0
```

but this takes too long on large sets of data (500+ rows)

I'm looking for something ***faster and more elegant***.

The dataframe should look like this when it is done (notice the bottom row has not been altered):

```
df = 

       time  price  volume      PV  flag  PVsum_2  Vsum_2      VWMA_2
dtime                                                                
16:00  1800  100.1     6.0  600.60   1.0  1268.15    12.5  101.452000
15:00  1740  102.7     6.5  667.55   1.0  1253.45    11.9  105.331933
14:00  1680  108.5     5.4  585.90   1.0  1249.29    11.7  106.776923
13:00  1620  105.3     6.3  663.39   1.0  1348.83    12.7  106.207087
12:00  1560  107.1     6.4  685.44   1.0  1419.58    13.5  105.154074
11:00  1500  103.4     7.1  734.14   1.0  1416.20    13.8  102.623188
10:00  1440  101.8     6.7  682.06   1.0  1318.80    12.9  102.232558
09:00  1380  102.7     6.2  636.74   1.0  1215.86    11.9  102.173109
08:00  1320  101.6     5.7  579.12   1.0   698.88     6.9  101.286957
07:00  1260   99.8     1.2  119.76   1.0   360.24     3.6  100.066667
06:00  1200  100.2     2.4  240.48   1.0   621.51     6.3   98.652381
05:00  1140   97.7     3.9  381.03   1.0   897.39     9.1   98.614286
04:00  1080   99.3     5.2  516.36   1.0  1407.25    14.1   99.804965
03:00  1020  100.1     8.9  890.89   1.0  1628.89    16.1  101.173292
02:00   960  102.5     7.2  738.00   1.0  1413.35    13.7  103.164234
01:00   900  103.9     6.5  675.35   0.0     0.00     0.0    0.000000
```

Eventually new data will be added to the top of the data frame as seen below, and will need to be updated again.

```
df = 
           time  price  volume      PV  flag  PVsum_2  Vsum_2  VWMA_2
    dtime                                                             
    19:00  1980  100.1     6.0  600.60   0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0
    18:00  1920  102.7     6.5  667.55   0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0
    17:00  1860  108.5     5.4  585.90   0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0
    16:00  1800  100.1     6.0  600.60   1.0  1268.15    12.5  101.452000
    15:00  1740  102.7     6.5  667.55   1.0  1253.45    11.9  105.331933
    14:00  1680  108.5     5.4  585.90   1.0  1249.29    11.7  106.776923
    13:00  1620  105.3     6.3  663.39   1.0  1348.83    12.7  106.207087
    12:00  1560  107.1     6.4  685.44   1.0  1419.58    13.5  105.154074
    11:00  1500  103.4     7.1  734.14   1.0  1416.20    13.8  102.623188
    10:00  1440  101.8     6.7  682.06   1.0  1318.80    12.9  102.232558
    09:00  1380  102.7     6.2  636.74   1.0  1215.86    11.9  102.173109
    08:00  1320  101.6     5.7  579.12   1.0   698.88     6.9  101.286957
    07:00  1260   99.8     1.2  119.76   1.0   360.24     3.6  100.066667
    06:00  1200  100.2     2.4  240.48   1.0   621.51     6.3   98.652381
    05:00  1140   97.7     3.9  381.03   1.0   897.39     9.1   98.614286
    04:00  1080   99.3     5.2  516.36   1.0  1407.25    14.1   99.804965
    03:00  1020  100.1     8.9  890.89   1.0  1628.89    16.1  101.173292
    02:00   960  102.5     7.2  738.00   1.0  1413.35    13.7  103.164234
    01:00   900  103.9     6.5  675.35   0.0     0.00     0.0    0.000000
```

Comment: Have you tried using `rolling()` method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using `pandas` in the right way. I'd recommend taking a quick look at a tutorial.

For starters, the following lines

```
df.insert(df.shape[1], "flag", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "PVsum_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "Vsum_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
df.insert(df.shape[1], "VWMA_2", list(repeat(0.0,len(df))))
```

can be much easier written as:

```
df['flag'] = 0
df['PVsum_2'] = 0
df['Vsum_2'] = 0
df['VWMA_2'] = 0
```

But it seems you don't even need to initialise those columns really.

You also don't need the `for` loop because you can align 2 dataframes, one being your original and another one is one where you've shifted all rows. For example:

```
df_shift = df.shift(-1)
```

You can then use normal vectorised calculations to achieve what you want, e.g.:

```
df['PVsum_2'] = df['PV'] + df_shift['PV']
df['Vsum_2'] = df['volume'] + df_shift['volume']
idx = df['Vsum_2'] != 0   # this is your check whether that value is different from 0 
df.loc[idx, 'VWMA_2'] = df.loc[idx, 'PVsum_2'] / df.loc[idx, 'VSum_2']  # and now use that index to only calculate VWMA_2 where the Vsum_2 was 0
```

Hopefully you get the idea and can make small adjustments to make it work exactly as you want.

Comment: This is fantastic! Can't remember why I spent so much effort making 0-filled columns. But thankyou for simplifying. Also, this is EXACTLY the solution I was looking for, Thankyou!! What used to take 30 minutes to run, now takes just 30 seconds. Thank you so much! If you know a good pandas tutorial, please recommend it.

Comment: I've started learning `pandas` using the following book. `https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.00-introduction-to-pandas.html`. There will be shorter tutorials or documents out there like `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html` but I think Jake's book provides a lot of extra context.